# Git GC hangs after finished writing objects

Tags: python, git, garbage-collection

I've spent a good amount of time searching for answers to my "Git GC hangs" problem but I have yet to found one.
I have a 1.8GB Python project on BitBucket and am trying to reduce the size of it. I followed [BitBucket guideline](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html#Reducerepositorysize-ReduceRep-DRAFT-Reducerepositorysize-Runningfilter-branch) to reduce a repo size, so I ran the following commands:

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

and below is the result:

```
Counting objects: 24762, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22140/22140), done.
Writing objects: 100% (24762/24762), done.
Total 24762 (delta 2437), reused 24762 (delta 2437)
```

And it hangs.

First time I tried, I waited an hour then canceled it. The second time, I let it run overnight and it still hung.

When I run `git count-objects -v` it shows my garbage size is 1.8 GB as followed:

```
count: 22
size: 7
in-pack: 148572
packs: 6
size-pack: 2913951
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 1
size-garbage: 1866072
```